# Re-publishing app on github after deleted gh-pages branch

Tags: reactjs, git, github, web-deployment, create-react-app

I made a mistake when delete gh-pages branch it made can't running. I tried to run `npm run deploy` or re create a new gh-pages branch and re-deploy but It doesn't work. How can I solve that?

Comment: Please elaborate "*doesn't work*".

Comment: Double check on github that the gh-pages source is pointing to the correct place (branch or otherwise).